# Good way of searching users? I have an idea but am unsure

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, backend

So this is all more theoretical since I am sorta planning ahead here but I have a generic Parse User class that I am trying to impliment a sort of search function so one user could search for his friends user.

My initial plan was to use the Parse Query contains method to find all the users who contain 'xxx' characters in their name. However.. I noticed that parse noted this would be slow with a large database.. ideally my hope for the app would be to have thousands of users. I Know that can sound a bit ambitious but that is what I am thinking.

Is parse just not the right platform for this?

I had thought about downloading all the user objects and then using local code to filter through them quickly but that surely couldn't be faster.

Would love to hear your guys thoughts!

Comment: Don't see why query on server is a problem

Comment: Hi charlieftl, in Parse's docs they used that method would be slow

Comment: Maybe take a look at this link: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea could work, but it could be slow. You can do some things to make it a bit faster, but contains is always going to be slow for the server to do. If you can change to 'begins with' instead of contains that will be faster. Exact matches should be faster again.

If you limit the search results that would help. So, as the user types, don't make any request to the server until 3 characters have been typed, and set the query limit to 5 results. Ideally also add a timer so if the user types a fourth character within 1 second the request isn't made. If the request is made and another character is typed cancel the current request before making a new one.

As more characters are typed in you could extend the limit to get more results.

Definitely don't download everything and search locally. Your users should also only really be accessible to cloud code because it can use the master key (your users should have an ACL which denies access to other users).

Comment: Boy I feel like an idiot! Those our much better ideas!!

Comment: I need to look into ACL however..